# How to install npm packages from Telerik private repository in VSTS build?

Tags: npm, telerik, azure-pipelines

I have a nice application where I'm using Telerik's Kendo UI for Angular 2. It is getting better and better. I would like to setup my builds in VSTS where installing packages, compiling TypeScript files are part of the build. Getting packages from Telerik repository requires authentication. I haven't found so far any usable description how to do it.

[Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/build-agents/) says that I should either directly authenticate or use .npmrc file and refers to an [MS site](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/npm/npmrc#project-vs-user-configuration).

The funny thing is that npm login (which is needed to connect Telerik's npm repo) does not accept username and password as parameter (doesn't matter how the community screams for it). I don't know why Telerik refers to this.

The .npmrc option is also funny, because it says that I should use vsts-npm-auth package to get credentials. I assume it means that I'll get the credentials of the build machine and it will be written in .npmr file. It is not a good solution for me. I got the build machines from a pool and the credentials rather a strongly limited credentials (enough fora build machine and nothing more) which does not equal my username and password at Telerik.

So, that's where my story ends and I need some help from you guys. How to do it? Did I misunderstand something? Is there anybody out there who did it?

Comment: Any more feedback?

Comment: I don't know, and I haven't checked whether MS guys done anything or not. That time I check the npm packages in so I could build.

Answer (score 0):

First, vsts-npm-auth is used for VSTS.

Secondly, after logging in (npm login) the .npmrc will be populated with an authentication token that can be copied to build agents or store file per-project. So try to use this .npmrc file and check the result.

Answer (score 0):

It figured out that vsts-npm-auth [doesn't work together](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3805) other private repositories than VSTS feeds. I let the team know and they, hopefully, will implement it.